# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Project\Router\Hello' not found

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

It's my first time using Composer and I'm getting a little bit batty trying to figure out why it is not picking up my namespaces.

In my `project/` directory:

```
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── composer.phar
├── README.md
├── vendor (truncated)
└── src
    ├── Config.php
    ├── Handler.php
    └── Router.php
```

src/Config.php

```
<?php
$project_root = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..');
$autoload = $project_root . '/vendor/autoload.php';
?>
```

src/Router.php

```
<?php namespace Project\Router;
include_once("Config.php");
require $autoload;

use Project\Handler;

Hello::world();
?>
```

src/Handler.php

```
<?php namespace Project\Handler;

include_once("Config.php");
require $autoload;

class Hello {
    public function world() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}
?>
```

composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Project\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

`http://127.0.1.1/project/src/Router.php`:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Project\Router\Hello' not found in /path/to/project/src/Router.php:38(not actual line) Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /path/to/project/src/Router.php on line 38(not actual line)

I am able to use foreign dependencies so my general Composer setup seems ok. I just can't figure out where I'm screwing up on my own namespaces.

Comment: Just for kicks, have you tried using `\Project\Handler\Hello::world();` instead of `use`?

Comment: @Machavity Yes I most certainly have. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be misinterpreting how PSR4 works.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Project\\": "src"
    }
}
```

This config means if you request the class Project\Handler\Hello from the autoloader it is going to check the path `src\Handler\Hello.php` (Which doesn't exist.)

If you change your directory structure to the following it will work:

```
└── src
    ├── Config.php
    ├── Router.php
    └── Handler
        └── Hello.php (renamed from Handler.php)
```

Also, neither Config.php or Router.php contain classes, which defeats the point of using a class autoloader.

Give this a read: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/